# Wildcards in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regular expression that finds the word *tjuv* (thief in swedish), which can be assembled with other words (see below for examples) and/or come in different conjugations.

Examples:

- cykeltjuv
- biltjuv
- tjuvarna
- inbrottstjuvs

The one below works for *tjuv* and *tjuvs* (a thief's), but what about the other conjugations as well as combinations with other words?

```
/tjuv(?:s){0,1}/ig
```

Now that I've learned you a little swedish it's fair that you learn me some regular expressions ;-)

**EDIT:** To be more specific, there's actually no case I can think of that shouldn't match with the word tjuv.

What I am doing is searching through phrases where the word *tjuv* exists, for example (translated to english):

```
1. När en familj kom hem från en utlandssemester upptäckte de att en inbrottstjuv
   hade varit i farten. <- MATCH!

2. På juldagen hade en cykeltjuv varit framme och stulit en cykel. <- MATCH


3. Violer är blå och rosor är röda <- No 'tjuv' and therefor no match
```

Comment: `/tjuv(?:s){0,1}/ig` is much too complicated - use `/tjuvs?/ig` instead.

Comment: First is bike thief? What about just `/.*tjuv.*/` ?

Comment: @BryanGlazer: So it's actually THAT easy?

Comment: That would match `tjuv` surrounded by anything. Do you need something more specific?

Comment: What kinds of strings should __not__ match? _Not matching_ is the real meat of regex.

Comment: It looks like `tjuvs?`, anchored at either the start or end of the string, would be a viable regex, something like `(?:^tjuvs?)|(?:tjuvs?$)` perhaps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is what you want, the word "tjuv" with other letters before and/or ahead:

```
/[a-z]*tjuv[a-z]*/ig
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33enr)

But `[a-z]` is a character class covering only the ASCII characters a to z (Case independent because of the `i` modifier). But I think swedish has also some characters that are not included in that range.

So either you

- add the missing characters to the character class

or

- dependend on your regex flavour you can use `\p{L}` instead.

  `\p{L}` is a [Unicode code point](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop), matching every letter in any language. Would then look like:

  ```
    /\p{L}*tjuv\p{L}*/ig
  ```

Comment: Ah, got it. But what's the difference between /\p{L}*tjuv\p{L}/ig and \w*(tjuv)\w* (from another answer), which looks less complicated?

Comment: @holyredbeard, `\w` is a predefined characterclass called "word character", that covers letters, digits and the underscore and this depending on the regex flavour either Unicode or ASCII based.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info! Is it possible to combine with other words with the OR char, like this? /inbrott|stöld|\p{L}*tjuv\p{L}*/ig ?

Comment: @holyredbeard, Of course, it is. Try the Regexr link I used, this is a wonderful tool to test regexes.

Answer (score 3):

i dont think that

```
/.*tjuv.*/
```

is good. it matches all text. This is better:

```
\w*(tjuv)\w*
```

this matches all words from your list. (and all words i with "tjuv" in it)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand the question, you are looking for words that contain *any* string before and/or after `tjuv`. In regular expressions, you normally can use the dot `.` to denote an arbitrary character. Therefore `tjuv.` matches `tjuvA`, `tjuvX`, `tjuvs`, ...
If you want an arbitrary number of such characters, use the star `*`. With `tjuvs.*` you can match `tjuvABC`, `tjuvs`, `tjuv` (then the star expands to zero characters!), ...

So I think `/.*tjuv.*/` could be something you want. However, here `.` also matches white space characters, so the regexp also matches `something xxxtjuvyyy somethingelse`, which might not be what you want.

It might be good to see some words that should match (or should not match). More than that, it would be a good idea to specify what programming language you are using.